# Cancel a thread within another thread

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, ipc

I have a multithreaded program. All I am doing in the main method is setting up multiple connections between clients and the server.

Each client runs this thread. 
Now this thread has another thread within it.

What I want to do is close the connection at the end of the thread. 
This is the code I am using. I have no idea why it does not work. Can anyone help me please?

```
void *thread_function(void * sock_desc){

  //get the socket descriptor
  int sock = *(int*)sock_desc;
  int n;
  int * sock2 = malloc(4);
  *sock2 = sock;

  pthread_t update_thread;
  pthread_create(&update_thread, NULL, updater, (void*)sock2);
  //do something

  pthread_cancel(update_thread);
  close(sock); //close the connection
  free(sock_desc); 
  free(sock2);

  return (void *)0;

}//close thread_function()
```

Comment: Where do you get `update_thread`? Who calls `pthread_create` and what does that call look like? Don't `malloc(4)`, `malloc(sizeof(int))` and cast to int*.  The threads cancelation state is not guaranteed.  Do a `man pthread_cancel`

Comment: update_thread is declared in thread_function as well

Comment: is there any other way how i can close the connection then?

Comment: It will help us if you add the code of `update_thread `. In my experience i use some flags into the code of the methods that is running the thread to check if it continues with the job or finish it, that means that the thread is finished. So, that is the reason that i want to see the `update_thread ` code. Also considere that the `pthread_cancel()` sends a cancellation request to the  thread and it depends if the thread has the cancelability state. Check this link: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html